# NameError: uninitialized constant Factory in ruby

Tags: ruby, rake

I get error when I run this code:

```
Factory.define :fake_address, :class => 'Address' do |a|
  a.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  a.last_name  { Faker::Name.last_name }
end

NameError: uninitialized constant Factory
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be `FactoryGirl`? Try this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :fake_address, :class => 'Address' do |a|
    a.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    a.last_name  { Faker::Name.last_name }
  end
end
```

Comment: I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)` Looks like this is not the solution.

Comment: I think you messed up things a bit. I updated my answer.